# Seaborn: how to plot wind speed v direction on circular plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Using Seaborn 0.6.0 if I have a pandas df that looks like this (only much longer):

```
windSpeed  windBearing
15.37          165
17.49          161
16.41          154
15.54          164
17.38          162
17.80            0
17.36          181
17.35          181
15.96          175
15.86          157
```

How can I plot the windBearing as a circular grid, representing compass direction and the windSpeed as rays emanating from the center with speed represented by length of the ray?

Comment: I don't know if seaborn has a way to do wind roses, but have you seen http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_bar_demo.html ?

Comment: This is a matplotlib question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mwaskom says in comments, this is straight matplotlib, not Seaborn.  Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import radians

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.scatter(x=[radians(x) for x in df['windBearing'].values], y=df['windSpeed'].values)
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
```

yields this chart:

[image]

As usual, importing Seaborn beforehand does make the chart more attractive; the same code will then yield:

[image]